# Creating a GitHub hook for when a pull requested is opened

Tags: github, jira, github-api, pull-request

I'm trying to setup a GitHub hook which sends a POST to a url when a pull request is opened. This post should contain all the relevant details of the pull request, however I have added a url to the "Web-Hook URLS" on GitHub and tested that with request bin and found that it only sends a POST when I do git commit.

Is it possible to get GitHub to send a POST when I open a new pull request?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved by using this gist :

https://gist.github.com/bjhess/2726012